# rank top 5 sales by date

Tags: sql

hello would like to know how to get the rank of the top 5 sales.

I have the following table:

```
date          product      value
31/01/2018    calca        100
31/01/2018    calca        50
31/01/2018    camisa       30
31/01/2018    camisa       30
31/01/2018    sapato       75
31/01/2018    bermuda      100
31/01/2018    meia         10
31/01/2018    tenis        65
31/01/2018    luva         20
31/01/2018    luva         20
31/01/2019    calca        100
31/01/2019    calca        50
31/01/2019    camisa       30
31/01/2019    camisa       30
31/01/2019    sapato       75
31/01/2019    bermuda      100
31/01/2019    meia         10
31/01/2019    tenis        65
31/01/2019    luva         20
31/01/2019    luva         20
```

Expected result 5 total sales by date.

```
date          prodct       value   rank
31/01/2018    calca        150       1
31/01/2018    bermuda      100       2
31/01/2018    sapato       75        3
31/01/2018    tenis        65        4
31/01/2018    camisa       60        5
31/01/2019    calca        150       1
31/01/2019    bermuda      100       2
31/01/2019    sapato       75        3
31/01/2019    tenis        65        4
31/01/2019    camisa       60        5
```

If anyone has a simple solution, thank you.

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: You need to also explain how you want to handle ties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` or `dense_rank()` (if you have a ties with value) :

```
select t.*
from (select date, product, sum(value) as value,
             dense_rank() over (partition by date order by sum(value) desc) as rank
      from table t
      group by date, product
     ) t
where rank <= 5;
```

Comment: I need the 5 sales limited by data
 example:
 5 sales of 2017/01
 5 sales of 2017/02
 5 sales of 2017/03 ...

Answer (score 1):

In `SQL` you would usually go like this:

```
SELECT T.date,
    T.product,
    T.value
FROM (
    SELECT T.date,
            T.product,
            T.value,
            row_number() OVER(partition by T.date order by T.value desc) AS grouped
    FROM dbo.sales AS T
    ) AS T
WHERE T.grouped <= 5;
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: I need the 5 sales limited by data example: 5 sales of 2017/01 5 sales of 2017/02 5 sales of 2017/03

Answer (score 1):

You need an aggregation, with window functions.  Something like this:

```
select date, product, value
from (select date, product, sum(value) as value,
             row_number() over (partition by date order by sum(value) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by date, product
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5
order by date, value desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP (5) date ,product 
      ,value
      ,rank () over (order by value desc) rank_order
  FROM TableA
```

Comment: SQL Server syntax TOP is not valid ISO/ANSI SQL standard where the sql tag is about..